# DataFrame fastest way to update rows without a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Creating a scenario:

Assuming a dataframe with two series, where `A` is the input and `B` is the result of `A[index]*2`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [2, 4, 6]})
```

Lets say I am receiving a 100k row dataframe and searching for errors in it (here `B->0` is invalid):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [2, 0, 6]})
```

Searching the invalid rows by using

```
invalid_rows = df.loc[df['A']*2 != df['B']]
```

I have the `invalid_rows` now, but I am not sure what would be the fastest way to overwrite the invalid rows in the original `df` with the result of `A[index]*2`?

Iterating over the `df` using `iterrows()` is an option but slow if the `df` grows. Can I use `df.update()` for this somehow?

Working solution with a loop:

```
index = -1
for row_index, my_series in df.iterrows():
  if myseries['A']*2 != myseries['B']:
    df[index]['B'] = myseries['A']*2
```

But is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: why not just `df['B'] = df['A'] * 2`?

Comment: Was thinking the same, but it's probably just simplified example.

Comment: @Erfan: Exactly - It is simplified to catch the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html), [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['A'].mul(2).ne(df['B'])
# same as: m = df['A'] * 2 != df['B']
df.loc[m, 'B'] = df['A'].mul(2)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  6
```

---

`m` returns a boolean series which marks the row where `A * 2 != B`

```
print(m)

0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: So from the original naming above it should be possible to do `df.loc[invalid_rows, 'B'] = df['A'].mul(2)`.. If I understand your answer correctly.